# does not enter the controller from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

when I click on the link does not enter my controller

so I have it declared

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href='@Url.Action("Register", "Account", new { Tipo = "Proveedores" })'>Cotizador Express</a>
    </li>                            
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
//public async Task<ActionResult> Register(LoginViewModel model)
public ActionResult Register(LoginViewModel model)
{
    return View("x");
}
```

Comment: You decorated your action with `[HttpPost]` while the `a` tag sends a `GET` request.

Comment: you need to change `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]` as you are making a get request to action method and it's better to use action link instead of Url.Action

Comment: I already change it and it still does not work
  <li> @ Html.ActionLink ("Cotizador Express", "Register", "Account", null) </ li>

Comment: and change it from [httpPost] to [httpGet]

Comment: Remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute from the controller action if you did not place the link in a `<form>` with a token that is being sent back to the server (using e.g. a submit button).

Comment: if you already delete [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from the beginning but it still does not work, and also previously probe with a button and it works well, the problem is that it has to be a link since it is added to a menu but this link does not work

Answer (score -1):

The following way should work:

```
[this is not a link]<a href="<%: Url.Action("Register", "Account", new { Tipo = "Proveedores" })>Cotizador Express</a>
```

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: sorry this should work i guess :<a href="<%: Url.Action("Register", "Account", new { Tipo = "Proveedores" })>Cotizador Express</a>

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to understand how to write a good answer then edit the answer with the expected information and context to help the person who asked the question.